# [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: custom validator check failed for prop "time"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datetime, countdown

I have a countdown timer, and is working well, but, in console i have this error: `[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: custom validator check failed for prop "time".` and i think is someting about datetime output, if i put `:time="new Date('03/09/2021 00:00:00').getTime()"` the error will be removed and this im trying to achive, but if i do like this: `:time="new Date(dataInscrieri.data_inscrieri).getTime()"` from mysql datetime the error is present. Some help? Many thanks!

Code:

```
 <countdown :time="new Date(dataInscrieri.data_inscrieri).getTime() - new Date().getTime()">

            <template slot-scope="props">

              <div class="single-counter">
                <span class="timer number mb-2">{{ props.days }}</span>
                <span>Zile</span>
              </div>

              <div class="single-counter">
                <span class="timer number mb-2">{{ props.hours }}</span>
                <span>Ore</span>
              </div>

              <div class="single-counter">
                <span class="timer number mb-2">{{ props.minutes }}</span>
                <span>Minute</span>
              </div>

              <div class="single-counter">
                <span class="timer number mb-2">{{ props.seconds }}</span>
                <span>Secunde</span>
              </div>

            </template>
          </countdown>

export default { 
  data () {
    return {
      dataInscrieri: [] 
    }
  },
  components: {
    'countdown': VueCountdown,
    StatisticsCardLine
  },
  created () {
    //  Data inscrieri eveniment
    this.$http.get('/api/users/data-inscrieri/event')
      .then((response) => { this.dataInscrieri = response.data.results })
      .catch((error)   => { console.log(error) }) 
  }  
}
```

dataInscrieri.data_inscrieri output from db is:

```
2020-11-02T22:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: `dataInscrieri` seems to be an Array ... `dataInscrieri: []` ... so, it won't have a property called `data_inscrieri` ... is `response.data.results` an Array of objects (even if it's an Array of length 1 it's still an Array), or a single Object with a property `data_inscrieri` ... perhaps, `this.dataInscrieri = response.data.results[0]` will help - though, I'd personally also change the data definition if that's the case

Comment: Nope,..  results[0] brings me ''Cannot read property '0' of undefined''

Comment: so `response.data.results` is undefined!? there's the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `dataInscrieri.data_inscrieri` is valid time and I see in `VueCountdown`  [prop -> :time](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/vue-countdown#time) is `Number` type, when you send other than a number, Vue throws `Invalid Prop type` type warning.

I think, you can use method to covert the time to number. This will help you to add check before sending time to Countdown component.

```
<countdown :time="getTime(dataInscrieri.data_inscrieri)">....
...

methods: {
   getTime(date) {
     const datetime = new Date(date)
     return datetime !== 'Invalid Date' ? datetime.getTime() - new Date().getTime() : null
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, still Invalid prop: custom validator check failed for prop "time". Error in console

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz for it?

Comment: I have do this: this.time = this.getTime(this.dataInscrieri.data_inscrieri) and :time="time" and seams the error is gone, Thank you!

Comment: Yes!  Thank you for your help, u are great Naren, best regards!

Answer (score 0):

replace your `getTime()` function to this:

```
<countdown :time="getTime(dataInscrieri.data_inscrieri)">....
...

<script>
import VueCountdown from '@chenfengyuan/vue-countdown';
import moment from 'moment';

export default {
    components: {
        VueCountdown
    },
    methods: {
        getTime(date) {
            return moment(timer).isAfter(moment()) ? moment(date).toDate() - moment().toDate() : 0
        }
    },
};
</script>
```